# CSS attribute selector, Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, Android 4.4.2

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a really nasty bug while testing a site on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, which we can't figure out. We think it is a device- or androidversion-specific problem, so we hope people here with experience in one of those 2 can maybe help us.

Device: Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, SM-T315
Android: 4.4.2

We set an attribute depending on a value:

```
if(test42 > 0) {
    ellipsis_box.setAttribute("data-overflow", "true");
    ellipsis_box.getElementsByTagName("div")[1].addEventListener('click', showEllipsisText);
}
else
    ellipsis_box.setAttribute("data-overflow", "false");
```

Nothing special, just adding an attribute to an element.
Then we just have in our css:

```
.sectionTextfeld[data-overflow="true"] .ellipsis {display: block;}
.sectionTextfeld[data-overflow="false"] .ellipsis {display: none;}
```

Nothing special either... it works perfectly fine except on that device. And maybe others we can't test, that's why we would like some more info on this. Searching doesn't help.
We tried some stuff, !important to check if it really isn't overriden, setting "" on and off for attribute-name and -value, attribute-name without hyphen, whatever stupid thing could be misinterpreted... nothing!

We could rewrite the code to use classes instead, but that would not really be a fix and it's not worth it if there is only a few devices out there that don't work. After all we can just default the div to block and well, it's always there, whatever...

Did I mention that we are interested WHY it doesn't work? :)

Thanks in advance!
Inu

Comment: Might be something to look at, but make sure that javascript is enabled on that device.

Comment: Rest of the site works, it's a rather huge project, so... also we "debugged" with alerts (is there another way for those devices?) and the attribute was definately set, at least getattribute could fetch it

Comment: Use chrome dev tools... Try to connect the tablet to a PC through a data cable, then access "chrome://devices/", and see what the console returns.

Comment: This only works when you use Chrome on your Device, not with the native browser... Chrome would be no problem, no bugs there